# Can a ArrayBuffer of Abstract Class hold members of derived class in Scala?

Tags: scala, abstract-class, derived-class, arraybuffer

I am defining an ArrayBuffer of Abstract class as follows.

```
abstract class Transformation(tableName: List[String],operation: List[String], outputTable: String){}
var transformationArray: ArrayBuffer[Transformation] = ArrayBuffer()
```

Can this ArrayBuffer contain elements of a derived class ?

```
class Map(tableName: List[String], newColumn: String, operation: List[String], outputTable: String) 
extends Transformation(tableName: List[String],operation: List[String], outputTable: String) {

}

transformationArray += new Map(tableName,newColumn,operation,outputTable)
```

I cannot access values of Map from the transformationArray

Answer (score 1):

Class constructors default to private. Add `val` to change that.

```
abstract class Transformation(val tableName   :List[String]
                             ,val operation   :List[String]
                             ,val outputTable :String)
```

Now you can access them.

```
transformationArray.head.outputTable  //res0: String = tbl
```

Comment: Thanks. I can access the variables defined in the Abstract Class but not the Derived class Variables(newColumn). Is there any way to implement abstract class pointer points to derived class in Scala ?

Comment: You can't access `newColumn` if it is **private** and I've already pointed out how to change that. I don't know what "abstract class pointer points to derived class" means. Scala doesn't have pointers the way languages such as C have.

Comment: I changes newColumn to var. But, I still cannot access it. Only derived class members which are part of the base class can be accessed.

Comment: Actually you are correct, changing `newColumn` to `val` (or `var`) won't help because, from the compiler's perspective, all the elements in `transformationArray` are of type `Transformation`, which has no `newColumn` member data. It might have more member data outside of the `transformationArray` but inside that information is completely walled off. If you tell the compiler, "this is a collection of `Transformation` elements," then that what the compiler will allow you to access. You would have to use something like pattern matching to extract the elements as full `Map` types.